# C# LINQ group collection by attribute then sort each group by explicit order defined by a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

I have a collection of C# objects that I want to

1. group on a given attribute
2. then sort each group by another attribute.
   The sort order is explicitly defined by a list.
3. Then I want to get only the top item from each group

For instance, consider:

```
data = [
  {​​​​​"name": "Alice", "country": "UK", "age": 30}​​​​​,
  {​​​​​​​"name": "Bob", "country": "KE", "age": 20}​​​​​​​,
  {​​​​​​​"name": "Charlie", "country": "UK", "age": 30}​​​​​​​,
  {​​​​​​​"name": "Alice", "country": "KE", "age": 40}​​​​​​​,
  {​​​​​​​"name": "Bob", "country": "AU", "age": 50}​​​​​​​,
  {​​​​​​​"name": "David", "country": "USA", "age": 25}​​​​​​​,
]
```

I want to group by `name` then sort each group by `country` to follow an explicit order specified in another collection such as:

```
var countryOrder = new List<string> { "UK", "KE", "AU", "USA"};
```

Then I want to select only top members of each group based on this order so that I'd end up with a list of objects unique on name (e.g. one `Alice` from either the `UK`, `KE`, `AU` or `USA`) but following the explitcly defined order of precedence.

Below is the expected output of the given example:

```
output = [
  {"name": "Alice", "country": "UK", "age": 30},
  {"name": "Bob", "country": "KE", "age": 20},
  {"name": "Charlie", "country": "UK", "age": 30},
  {"name": "David", "country": "USA", "age": 25},
]
```

I have tried using the code below:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var countryOrder =new List<string> { "UK", "KE", "AU", "USA"};
        
        var data = new List<ExampleDataClass> {
            new ExampleDataClass { Name = "Alice", Country = "UK", Age = 30 },
            new ExampleDataClass { Name = "Bob", Country = "KE", Age = 20 },
            new ExampleDataClass { Name = "Charlie", Country = "UK", Age = 30 },
            new ExampleDataClass { Name = "Alice", Country = "KE", Age = 40 },
            new ExampleDataClass { Name = "Bob", Country = "AU", Age = 50 },
            new ExampleDataClass { Name = "David", Country = "USA", Age = 25 }
        };
        
        var reducedData = data
            .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Select(g => g.OrderBy(item => countryOrder.IndexOf(item.Country)).Min())
            .ToList();
        
        reducedData.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(reducedData));
    }
}

class ExampleDataClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

`.Select(g => g.OrderBy(item => countryOrder.IndexOf(item.Country)).Min())` gives a run-time exception:

```
Run-time exception (line 50): At least one object must implement IComparable.

Stack Trace:

[System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.]
   at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectComparer`1.Compare(T x, T y)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Min[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Program.<>c__DisplayClassd.<Main>b__9(IGrouping`2 g) :line 50
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Program.Main() :line 49
```

Comment: `data` is a JSON array is correct?

Comment: Processing it as a collection of C# objects

Comment: data.GroupBy(g => g.name).Select(g => new { group = g.Key, items = g.OrderBy(g => g.country)}); - something like this, but you need to take in account country collection on OrderBy

Comment: You're expected to show an attempt at solving the problem at hand, not just tell us what you want to get.

Comment: @Flater I have put in a code attempt and expected output

Comment: `Min()` looks for the smallest of a collection of values that are inherently comparable with one another. You're looking to get the item from the collection where a specific property has the smallest value. That question is well addressed in the post I marked this as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution I have found:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var countryOrder =new List<string> { "UK", "KE", "AU", "USA"};
        
        var data = new List<ExampleDataClass> {
            new ExampleDataClass {
                Name = "Alice",
                Country = "UK",
                Age = 30,
            },
            
            new ExampleDataClass {
                Name = "Bob",
                Country = "KE",
                Age = 20,
            },
            
            new ExampleDataClass {
                Name = "Charlie",
                Country = "UK",
                Age = 30,
            },
            
            new ExampleDataClass {
                Name = "Alice",
                Country = "KE",
                Age = 40,
            },
            
            new ExampleDataClass {
                Name = "Bob",
                Country = "AU",
                Age = 50,
            },
            
            new ExampleDataClass {
                Name = "David",
                Country = "USA",
                Age = 25,
            }
        };
        
        var reducedData = data.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                             .Select(g => g.OrderBy(item => countryOrder.IndexOf(item.Country)).First())
                             .ToList();
        
        foreach (ExampleDataClass item in reducedData) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: \"{0}\", Country: \"{1}\", Age: {2}", item.Name, item.Country, item.Age));
        }
    }
}

class ExampleDataClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public string Country { get; set; }
    
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Output

```
Name: "Alice", Country: "UK", Age: 30
Name: "Bob", Country: "KE", Age: 20
Name: "Charlie", Country: "UK", Age: 30
Name: "David", Country: "USA", Age: 25
```

link to a dotnetfiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/6geHtk